# What kind of strange md5 check sum is this

Tags: md5, md5-file

I was downloading [kafka and the checksum file](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/kafka/0.8.2.1/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz.md5) looks like this:

```
kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz: 44 6E AB
                        1F 53 29
                        EB 03  66
                        29 26 AA
                        1C B0 84
                        5D
```

it looks like Hexadecimal to me, my question is how exactly do i compare it with the output of the command md5sum?

```
[foot@foo]# md5sum kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz 
446eab1f5329eb03662926aa1cb0845d  kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.tgz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is exactly the same, but in uppercase, and with spaces...

```
44 6E AB
1F 53 29
EB 03  66
29 26 AA
1C B0 84
5D
```

is the same as

```
44 6E AB 1F 53 29 EB 03 66 29 26 AA 1C B0 84 5D
```

and removing the spaces

```
446EAB1F5329EB03662926AA1CB0845D
```

and finally lower case

```
446eab1f5329eb03662926aa1cb0845d
```